# Setting up a P2P connection between two android phones?

Tags: android, real-time, p2p

I am trying to develop an android application, through I could share some files or other applications in real time(can be thought as a miniature version of remote desktop sharing). So I am trying to set up a P2P connection between 2 phones, but for that phones would be requiring IP address of each other. Is there any way by which I can get the IP address of the other device by just using the phone number. If not then how will I get to know the IP addresses of the devices?

Could you please post some other suggestions for setting up a real-time P2P connection ?

Answer (score 1):

The phones don't have public IP addresses, and aren't (usually) in the same subnet, so you can't just send IP packets directly from one to the other. You'll need a server to relay the packets. One way I've done this is to use the [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) library and an XMPP server like [OpenFile](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).